# Iterate over lists to get and store vectors "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96) into shape (0)"

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to create a 2D array X with as many rows as there are sentences in the sentences dataset, where each row is a vector describing that sentence. I tried the below code but it is giving me ValueError

```
# Calculate the length of sentences
n_sentences = len(sentences)

# Calculate the dimensionality of nlp
embedding_dim = nlp.vocab.vectors_length

# Initialize the array with zeros: X
X = np.zeros((n_sentences, embedding_dim))


# Iterate over the sentences
for idx, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    # Pass each each sentence to the nlp object to create a document
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    # Save the document's .vector attribute to the corresponding row in X
    X[idx, :] = doc.vector
```

A portion of the sentences datasets

```
sentences = sentences = [' i want to fly from boston at 838 am and arrive in denver at 1110 in the morning',
 ' what flights are available from pittsburgh to baltimore on thursday morning',
 ' what is the arrival time in san francisco for the 755 am flight leaving washington',
 ' cheapest airfare from tacoma to orlando',
 ' round trip fares from pittsburgh to philadelphia under 1000 dollars']
```

Am I missing something? any help will be highly appreciated :)

The full error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-91f65010e223> in <module>
     14     doc = nlp(sentence)
     15     # Save the document's .vector attribute to the corresponding row in X
---> 16     X[idx, :] = doc.vector

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96) into shape (0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due to your loading vectorless model. Try a model with vectors instead and you're fine to go:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md") ## <-- !!!

sentences = [' i want to fly from boston at 838 am and arrive in denver at 1110 in the morning',
 ' what flights are available from pittsburgh to baltimore on thursday morning',
 ' what is the arrival time in san francisco for the 755 am flight leaving washington',
 ' cheapest airfare from tacoma to orlando',
 ' round trip fares from pittsburgh to philadelphia under 1000 dollars']

# Calculate the length of sentences
n_sentences = len(sentences)

# Calculate the dimensionality of nlp
embedding_dim = nlp.vocab.vectors_length

# Initialize the array with zeros: X
X = np.zeros((n_sentences, embedding_dim))

for idx, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    # Pass each each sentence to the nlp object to create a document
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    # Save the document's .vector attribute to the corresponding row in X
    X[idx, :] = doc.vector
    
# idx = 0
# for doc in nlp.pipe(sentences):
#     X[idx, :] = doc.vector
#     idx += 1
```

Note commented use of `nlp.pipe` generator which should speed up execution and allow processing of bigger files.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for your answer, it make sense now. I am using 
'en_core_web_sm'

I am always confused with which one i should use sm or md like in ur case